# Как восстановить доступ к диску SSD?

Tags: ssd

Компьютер завис и после перезагрузки bios не видит диск ssd на котором была windows 10. Диск уже очень старый был kingstone 240gb.
Если зайти в ОС с другого диска с windows 10, то диск отображается в программе Diskpart
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же отображается в программе управление дисками. Но требует инициализации.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В программе виктория, он так же отображается, но там ошибки при сканировании
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как то зайти в его файловую систему и скопировать оттуда какие то файлы? Или диск уже полностью поврежден и не восстановится?

Answer (score 1):

Отвалился контроллер. Один раз мне такой перепаивали с донора в сервисе и 2 раза  подобные диски запускались на пару минут на холодную. Программно из него ничего не вытащить.